# How do I replace a list of phrases (NOT WORDS OR STRINGS) in a pandas DataFrame with a correct version

Tags: python, regex, pandas, replace

I know there have been a lot of similar answers, but none I can get to work for my situation. I have a DataFrame of brands with similar names. I need to replace all these variations of "Coke" with a single name "Coke".

The problem is replacement strings like "Coc" are turning "Coca Cola" into "Cokea Cola".
Equally I've tried regex \b and \w variations, but then I'll get "Coca Coke" or "Coke Cola" etc.

```
wrong_df = pd.DataFrame(["Coca Cola", "Coca", "Cola", "Coke", "Co"])
words_to_replace = ["Coca Cola", "Coca", "Cola", "Co"]
correct_word = 'Coke'

for word in words_to_replace:
    string = "r'^" + "{}".format(word) + "\\b"
    print(string)
    correct_df = wrong_df.replace(to_replace=string, value=correct_word, regex=True)
correct_df

# df_should_look_like_this = pd.DataFrame(["Coke", "Coca", "Coke", "Coke"])
```

Comment: You want `correct_df = wrong_df.replace(to_replace=r'^(?:{})\b'.format("|".join(sorted(words_to_replace,key=len,reverse=True))), value=correct_word, regex=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Just use `pandas`' `replace()` method.

```
wrong_df.replace(words_to_replace, correct_word)
```

Result:

```
      0
0  Coke
1  Coke
2  Coke
3  Coke
4  Coke
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure whether I understood your question right, but a simple way to do this would simply be:

```
wrong_df = pd.DataFrame(["Coca Cola", "Coca", "Cola", "Coke", "Co"])
words_to_replace = ["Coca Cola", "Coca", "Cola", "Co"]
correct_word = 'Coke'

correct_df = wrong_df.replace(to_replace=words_to_replace, value=correct_word)
```

So no need to use regex.
The output is:

```
      0
0  Coke
1  Coke
2  Coke
3  Coke
4  Coke
```

Comment: You say "no need to use regex", but what will happen if there is `Coldfusion` like string?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Good note - however I think the list `words_to_replace` should be complete, meaning that all possible ways to misspell `correct_word` should be included in it. That is how I understood the question at least - maybe @thunt can clarify?

Comment: Hi yes my question was how to use regex (rather than the simple case above) to avoid partial string replacements. I.e. "Coca Cola" gets replaced to "Coca Coke". But @WiktorStribiżew your first answer has solved the problem, thankyou!

Comment: If you're interested, I ended up solving it like this:

df_copy[col] = [replacement_word if x in words_to_replace else x for x in dataframe_in[col]]

Comment: Also, I don't believe my question is a duplicate of others on here. No other answer I read solved this "partial word" matching problem.